# Snowflake : IN operator

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

so I want something as below in my query

```
select * from table a
where a.id in(select id, max(date) from table a group by id)
```

I am getting error here , as IN is equivalent to = .

how to do it?

example :

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-31-01 |
| 1 | 2022-21-03 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 2022-02-01 |

I need to get only one record based on date(max). The table has more columns than just id and date

so I need to something like this in snowflake

````
select * from table a
where id in(select id,max(date) from table a group by id)
```-----------------------
All solutions are working , if i select from table .

but  i have case statement in view where duplicate records are coming

example :

create or replace view v_test
as
select * from

(

select id,lastdatetime,*,
case when start_date < timestamp and timestamp < end
and move_date = '9999-12-31' then 'Y'
else 'N' end as IND

from table a
) a


so if any one select view where IND= 'Y', more than  1 records are coming
what i want is to select latest records for ID where IND='Y' and max(lastdatetime)

how to incorporate this logic in view?
````

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to get the latest record for each id?

```
select * 
from table a
qualify row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

So if we look at your sub-select:

using this "data" for the examples:

```
with data (id, _date) as (
select column1, to_date(column2, 'yyyy-dd-mm') from values
    (1, '2022-31-01'),
    (1, '2022-21-03'),
    (2, '2022-01-01'),
    (2, '2022-02-01')
)
```

```
select id, max(_date) 
from data
group by 1;
```

it gives:

| ID | MAX(_DATE) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-21 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 |

which makes it seem you want the "the last date, per id"

which can classically (ansi sql) be written:

```
select d.* 
from data as d
join (
    select 
        id, 
        max(_date) as max_date
    from data
    group by 1
) as c
    on d.id = c.id and d._date = c.max_date
;
```

| ID | _DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-21 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 |

which gives you "all the rows values". BUT if you have many rows with the same last date, you will get those, in the output.

Another methods is to use a ROW_NUMBER to pick one and only one row, which is the style of answer Mike has given:

```
with data (id, _date, extra) as (
select column1, to_date(column2, 'yyyy-dd-mm'), column3 from values
    (1, '2022-31-01', 'extra_a'),
    (1, '2022-21-03', 'extra_b_double_a'),
    (1, '2022-21-03', 'extra_b_double_b'),
    (2, '2022-01-01', 'extra_c'),
    (2, '2022-02-01', 'extra_d')
)
select *
from data
qualify row_number() over (partition by id order by _date desc) =1 ;
```

gives:

| ID | _DATE | EXTRA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-21 | extra_b_double_a |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | extra_d |

now if you want the "all rows of the last day" you method works, albeit the QUALIFY/ROW_NUMBER is faster. You can use RANK

```
with data (id, _date, extra) as (
select column1, to_date(column2, 'yyyy-dd-mm'), column3 from values
    (1, '2022-31-01', 'extra_a'),
    (1, '2022-21-03', 'extra_b_double_a'),
    (1, '2022-21-03', 'extra_b_double_b'),
    (2, '2022-01-01', 'extra_c'),
    (2, '2022-02-01', 'extra_d')
)
select *
from data
qualify dense_rank() over (partition by id order by _date desc) =1 ;
```

| ID | _DATE | EXTRA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-21 | extra_b_double_a |
| 1 | 2022-03-21 | extra_b_double_b |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | extra_d |

Now the last thing that it almost seems you are asking for, is "how do find the ID with the most recent data (here `1`) and get all rows for that"

```
with data (id, _date, extra) as (
select column1, to_date(column2, 'yyyy-dd-mm'), column3 from values
    (1, '2022-31-01', 'extra_a'),
    (1, '2022-21-03', 'extra_b_double_a'),
    (1, '2022-21-03', 'extra_b_double_b'),
    (2, '2022-01-01', 'extra_c'),
    (2, '2022-02-01', 'extra_d')
)
select *
from data
qualify id = last_value(id) over (order by _date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use the in operator with a subquery:

```
select * from table1 t1 where t1.id in (select t2.id from table2 t2);
```

Comment: i need  id based on max(date) here

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `IN` is possible to match on both columns:

```
select * 
from tab AS a
where (a.id, a.date) in (select id, max(date) from tab group by id);
```

For sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (id, date)
AS 
SELECT column1, to_date(column2, 'yyyy-dd-mm')
FROM VALUES
    (1, '2022-31-01'),
    (1, '2022-21-03'),
    (2, '2022-01-01'),
    (2, '2022-02-01');
```

Output:

[image]